# Do probabilities need to sum to 1 in a choice model?

Tags: r, stata, discrete-data, clogit, choice-modeling

We're create a discrete choice model, in which there are more than two alternative choices. There are some options for this, such as [the multinomial logit and the conditional logit.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_choice#Multinomial_Choice_without_Correlation_Among_Alternatives). We started with an alternative-specific conditional logit (McFadden’s choice) model, implemented [in Stata as `asclogit`](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/rasclogit.pdf). We want to move away from that to the plain conditional logit (it's faster, has implementations in R, etc.). With `asclogit`, for any group/case of choices the modeled probabilities of the choices summed to 1. This is desired; we *know* that one of the choices *will* be picked. When we moved to the more general conditional logit, this was no longer the case.

For some simple examples with three choices, all the modeled probabilities were above 1/3. So the probabilities were being consistently overestimated. The conditional logit can be interpreted as a choice model, but it can also be interpreted in other ways. As such, we're not surprised that the probabilities don't sum to 1. However, we're nervous. Is this an indication we've misspecified the model somehow? Or should we just do the obvious thing and, for each group/case of choices, normalize to a sum of 1 by dividing each probability by the collective sum?

---

Edit, for the benefit of posterity:
It turns out we just don't know Stata. In order to measure the modeled probabilities of each alternative, we used the command `pu0`. It needs to be `pc1`. Once we measured the correct probabilities, everything was as it should be.

Comment: When numbers sum to more than unity, they simply cannot be interpreted as probabilities of disjoint events: that directly violates the most basic of axioms. Good models parameterize the probabilities to *guarantee* they will sum to unity, so there might be the best place to investigate your situation: could you tell us more precisely how your models are managing to give such inconsistent numbers?

Comment: More briefly "what did you do?" -- it's not 100% clear what the model you fitted is doing. How is the model set up (what's the algebraic model for the probabilities)/ what does it assume about these probabilities?

Comment: I have voted to close this question as unclear because it just doesn't seem to contain enough information to help anyone understand what was done or what was accomplished by the posted solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the benefit of posterity:
It turns out we just don't know Stata. In order to measure the modeled probabilities of each alternative, we used the command `pu0`. It needs to be `pc1`. Once we measured the correct probabilities, everything was as it should be.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I am the author.

Comment: Then add an update to your question.

Comment: I did that before posting this answer.